# How to set initial values for the Application Tile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-tile

I would like my application tile to have the flip animation, and I have attempted to set these values in the codebehind of my MainPage, but for some reason the Application Tile does not perform the flip animation. I believe I set the back side values properly. What I have is as follows:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public void CreateApplicationTile()
    {
        var appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

        if (appTile != null)
        {
            var standardTile = new StandardTileData
            {
                Title = "ShareSky",
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Background.png", UriKind.Relative),
                BackTitle = "ShareSky",
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Background.png", UriKind.Relative),
                //BackContent = "click me!"                    
                BackContent = AppResource.Main_MainPage_ApplicationTile_BackContent
            };

            appTile.Update(standardTile);
        }
    }
```

As I understand, this method does not need to be associated with any events of any type (such as a click) to make it work. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong here? If I have to edit the WMAppManifest file, how would I correctly do this to incorporate the backside of the tile information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly question but are you actually calling "CreateApplicationTile" in your constructor?  If you didn't it would never activate.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateApplicationTile();
    }
```

I ran the following and got the nice happy rollovers.

```
   var appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString() == "/");
   if (appTile != null)
   {
        var standardTile = new StandardTileData
        {
                Title = "ShareSky",
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Background.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                BackTitle = "ShareSky",
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/flipped.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                BackContent = "backcontent load"
        };

        appTile.Update(standardTile);
     }
```